# How to import scss into Angular2 before @component

Tags: angular, sass

I follow https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components to make scss works for angualr2, most of them are good.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

import '../../public/css/styles.scss'; // this file is not imported

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

However, I have 2 questions:

1. Why `styles.scss` is imported before `@Component`, what's the diff
   to be embedded into `styleUrls`
2. `import '../../public/css/styles.scss';`does not work

Comment: Angular's approach on styles is also component based. Means you should use the 'styleUrls' property as you do. If you have global styles, you can add them to your .angular-cli.json.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, if use angular-cli, it is a very good answer. However, my project is a bit old and there is no angular-cli when it was created. Thank you as well.

Comment: I'd re-setup the project! There were a lot of changes between release candidates (I assume you're on an rc because you don't have ng-cli) and the major 2.x and even 4.x releases.